# Find Difference between the two sequence of points value in AmCharts?

Tags: charts

I am using the `AmCharts`. I need to display value in the balloon text , that value is not a value field.

For example : `X axis Value 0 , Y axis 1, (0,1) is 2 ; (1,2) is 5`.

I need to display the Difference between the values `(0,1)` and `(1,2)` - that means "3" as Balloon in the point `(1,2)`. Any ideas ?

Comment: No, this way it won't work. Specify which charts exactly you use (javascript, flash, silverlight, whatever) and whether you have access to the source code of the charts library.

Comment: I am using javascript area chart (amcharts). Here one example is there , specified the differnce between the two sequenced count . 

http://www.targetprocess.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/cumulative_flow_diagram.png

Like this I need to display . How can I implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the chart on your screenshot is possible to implement.

At first, add additional fields to your chart data, for example, `labelGraph1, labelGraph2`. Then you can use the `labelText` property of the `AmCharts.AmGraph` object.

```
var chartData = [{
    title: "Apples",
    value1: 24,
    value2: 28,
    labelGraph1: null,
    labelGraph2: null
}, {
    title: "Bananas",
    value1: 27,
    value2: 31,
    labelGraph1: null,
    labelGraph2: null
}, {
    title: "Cherries",
    value1: 27,
    value2: 39,
    labelGraph1: null,
    labelGraph2: null
}];

for(var i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
    chartData[i].labelGraph1 = chartData[i].value1;
    chartData[i].labelGraph2 = chartData[i].value2 - chartData[i].value1;
}

var chart;

AmCharts.ready(function () {
    // SERIAL CHART
    chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    chart.dataProvider = chartData;
    chart.categoryField = "title";

    // GRAPHS                                            
    var graph1 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph1.valueField = "value1";
    graph1.type = "line";
    graph1.fillAlphas = 0.6;
    graph1.labelText = "[[labelGraph1]]";
    chart.addGraph(graph1);

    var graph2 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph2.valueField = "value2";
    graph2.type = "line";
    graph2.fillAlphas = 0.6;
    graph2.labelText = "[[labelGraph2]]";
    chart.addGraph(graph2);

    // WRITE
    chart.write("chartdiv")
});
```

The only one difficulty is to calculate values of the displayed fields.
I did it so, and you should change that function according to your data:

```
for(var i = 0; i < chartData.length; i++) {
    chartData[i].labelGraph1 = chartData[i].value1;
    chartData[i].labelGraph2 = chartData[i].value2 - chartData[i].value1;
}
```